# python variable float format # ValueError: Format specifier missing precision

Tags: python, pandas, floating-point, decimal, valueerror

```
a = 0.000004545  # variable decimal . 

decimalNumber = 3  # decimal place

print(f' {a:.2f}') # Word Fine

print(f' {a:.decimalNumberf}') # ValueError: Format specifier missing precision
```

a = variable  float number. Sometimes 4 decimal sometimes 8 .
How can i fix it this problem ?

Thanks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use format instead of f-string:

```
print("{}".format(round(a, decimalNumberf)))
```